# Show all divs when all checkboxes are unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am try to do a quick and simple filter function on my website. Where users can check and uncheck the checkboxes to filter what they want to see.

Currently i'm using this script:

```
$(".filter-obj :checkbox").click(function() {
  $(".obj").hide();
  $(".filter-obj:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
    $("." + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

This is my HTML:

```
<ul class="filter-obj">
    <li>
       <div class="checkbox">
           <input class="filter-search" id="filter-obja" value="a" type="checkbox">
           <label for="filter-obja"> Object A</label>
       </div>
    </li>
    <li>
       <div class="checkbox">
           <input class="filter-search" id="filter-objb" value="b" type="checkbox">
           <label for="filter-objb"> Object B</label>
       </div>
    </li>
</ul>


<!-- my objects -->
<div class="obj a">Object A</div>
<div class="obj a">Object A</div>
<div class="obj b">Object B</div>
<div class="obj b">Object B</div>
```

It works perfectly well at showing only whats checked and hiding whats unchecked. However, I also want it to show all the divs again when everything is unchecked. Help?

Comment: post your html part?

Comment: @KarthikeyanSekar I have updated with my html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the length of checked boxes and if it returns 0(false) then show()

```
var check = $(".filter-obj :checkbox:checked").length;

if(!check) return $(".obj").show();
```

**Edit** Using **`return`** will stop the rest of the code from running.

```
$(".filter-obj :checkbox").click(function() {
    var check = $(".filter-obj :checkbox:checked").length;
    if(!check) return $(".obj").show();

    $(".obj").hide();
    $(".filter-obj:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
       $("." + $(this).val()).show();
    });

});
```

Comment: I this this is the logic that im trying to work around with however it is not working for me... could it be because theres a clash of the show/hide functions?

Comment: it's still not working... here's the fiddle i put with ur code inside.  https://jsfiddle.net/dLfse25a/2/

Comment: @flolaloop just add the `space` in the jquery selector `$(".filter-obj:checkbox:checked").length to $(".filter-obj :checkbox:checked").length`